# What is the Home Folder under /Library/Java for?

Tags: java, symlink

I installed Java 1.7 from the oracle site.  Looking at my folder structure, there is `/System/Library/Java` and `/Library/Java`.  Under `/Library/Java` there is a `Home` symlink that goes to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home`.  I had to point my IDE (IntelliJ) to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home` which is a little weird in that there is a `Home` directory, but that `Home` is not the same `Home` as is in `Library/Java`.

Did I mess something up in my install? Is this symlinked `Home` gonna mess me up at some point?

The symlinked `Home` goes to Java 1.6 (which is what I believe Mavericks ships with?), but I have access to 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

No you didn't mess anything up.  My Java 7 is in the same location as yours.  The Home symlink will not mess you up.

BTW you can add this to your .bash_profile to set your java home environment variable

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.7 2>/dev/null`
```

Comment: Why output the std_error to null?